# mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given

Tags: php

receiving this error:

```
 mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given
```

Not sure why and have browsed a lot of topics on here trying to figure it out. I know it has something to do with my query, but I just can't put the pieces together.

Thanks for the assistance, I appreciate it!

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])){
     echo "Please login first.";
    exit();
}else{
include ("header.php");
require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');
$id=$_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_id=$id"; 
$result = @mysqli_query ($query);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($num > 0) { 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
?>
        <form action="update.php" method="post">
        <p>Title: <input name="title" size=50 value="<? echo $row['title']; ?>"></p>
        <p>Author: <input name="author" size=50 value="<? echo $row['author']; ?>"></p>
        <p>Post: <input name="post" size=50 value="<? echo $row['post']; ?>"></p>
        <p>
        <input type=submit value=update>
        <input type=reset value=reset>
        <input type=hidden name="post_id" value="<? echo $row['post_id']; ?      >">
        </form>
<?
    } 
} 
}
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Do change `<? echo $row['post_id']; ?      >">` to `<? echo $row['post_id']; ?>">`

Comment: Plus, this `$id=$_GET['id'];` should most likely be `$id=$_GET['post_id'];` Consider putting quotes in `<input type=submit value=update><input type=reset value=reset>` also.

Comment: Ah whoops, I formatted it wrong when I posted it on here. I do have it like that in the actual file. Nice catch though! Made sure to double check.

Comment: I also suggest that you use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET` if you're using that whole code inside the same page, since you're using POST and asking the query to fetch a GET id method.

Comment: I think you need to remove `@` in `mysqli_query` and  probably have a look in `require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');` whether DB connections are fine for this page

Comment: for this, since it's only accessible by the admin I was using get. It pulls from the url which ends with the updateform.php?id=6

I did change it though :D

Comment: As I said, you're using `echo $row['post_id'];` and `$id=$_GET['id'];` so I don't know if there's a relation between those two or not. @user3610604 if so, they don't match.

Comment: I definitely changed it as what you said does make perfectly good sense and sounds like overall good form. Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved then? @Wolfy36 and forgot to mention the `name="post_id"`

Comment: Unfortunately those changed didn't fix the error :( its still pointing at the  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result error

Comment: Time for you to use `var_dump();` on your variables and use error reporting at the top of your files `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

In the line `$result = @mysqli_query ($query);` the `@` will silence any errors.  Check that `$result` is not `false`, `null`, or some other error before proceeding.

You may want to go without the `@` until you have it working so you can get more meaningful error messages.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for that! It switched to showing $query as needing to parameters so I changed it to $result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);

It switches the error to mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ...which makes me think that adding $dbc didnt fix it.

Comment: mysqli_query returns false in the event of an error.  Did you verify that `$dbc` is a valid link first?

Comment: The $dbc is set up correctly and works on all of the other pages for the website, I went back and checked over it and didn't see any issues. Gah, so confused

Comment: Have you tried using `print_r` or `var_dump` to output the values of `$id`, `$query`, and `$result`?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that in the last section the code is not properly intented..like `value="<? echo $row['post_id']; ?`..Then secondly as Joe said the `@` symbol supress errors..So you need to remove those @symbol from your code..So the code must be ..

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])){

 echo "Please login first.";

exit();

}else{

include ("header.php");

require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');

$id=$_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_id=$id"; 

$result = mysqli_query ($query);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($num > 0) { 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

?>

    <form action="update.php" method="post">
    <p>Title: <input name="title" size=50 value="<? echo $row['title']; ?>"></p>
    <p>Author: <input name="author" size=50 value="<? echo $row['author']; ?>"></p>
    <p>Post: <input name="post" size=50 value="<? echo $row['post']; ?>"></p>
    <p>
    <input type=submit value=update>
    <input type=reset value=reset>
    <input type=hidden name="post_id" value="<? echo $row['post_id']; ?>">
    </form>
```

Hope this one helps you ..If any problems regarding then comment below ..:)

Comment: When trying this, it brings up an additional error stating " mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, " :(

Comment: This means that you need to pass the function a valid mysqli link resource as well as the query you wish to perform. This lets the function know which established connection to the server to use...Try using mysql_connect()

Comment: `mysql_connect()`? OP is using `mysqli_*`

Comment: mysql_connect() is a mysqli_* function ??>...sorry my mistake ..he uses mysql instead of mysqli .so use mysql_connect()

Comment: You made the same mistake. It's `mysqli_connect()` by `mysqli_*` I meant OP is using `mysqli` functions and not `mysql`

Comment: if he is using mysqli he should connect with mysqli_connect() and if he is using mysql version he should connect with mysql_connect()..and sorry i made a mistake ..though ..:)

Comment: I've given up long ago on OP's question. I've given the OP a few suggestions with error reporting and `var_dump();` but I doubt he/she even used them. So, I am out of here ;-) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you must check the value of GET['id'] is having value or not and query is formed with appropriate data.
You might be getting the error because the result is null.
and also check the connection.